# How to add custom menu action and titlebar icon to JFrame

Tags: java, button, jframe, menuitem

I have a custom JFrame.  On the title bar I have an icon in the top left, a title, and then the standard minimize, maximize, and close buttons on the right.

When I click the icon in the title bar I get the standard options: Restore, Move, Size, Minimize, Maximize, Close.

How can I add my own menu option here?  I'd like to add and "Always On Top" option here.

Additionally I'd like to add a button next to the max,min,close buttons on the title bar to allow uses to toggle the "Always On Top" state of the JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own customized Components. To do that, create a new class which `extends JMenuBar` for example and override the methods which fit your needs. Very often, for example, one wants to override `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

That is not what you want, 'though. Customizing the `JMenuBar` wont work as you expect it to. The "JMenuBar" is another bar below the title bar. I am Mac user, but as far as my knowledge goes, it is *not* possible to customize the *title* bar, because that isn't handled by the JVM. The only thing that is modifiable without using native code is the Icon in the top left.

**For further information on that, look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482969/is-it-possible-to-change-titlebar-color-of-jframe-or-jinternalframe) and the best answer there.** This will help you a lot.

Your problem (adding a button at the top for toggling the `alwaysOnTop` status) is best solved by creating normal instances of a JMenuBar, a JMenu and a JMenuItem.
To then add that MenuBar to your Frame, use `JFrame.setJMenuBar(JMenuBar)`. See also [How to use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).

I hope this helps!

Comment: how would I attach this JMenuBar to my JFrame?

Comment: Actually, I've written complete non-sense. You could create subclasses of some components, however this is not really neccessary as you can't change the **title** bar anyway. And customizing the MenuBar has no real effect to usability.

Comment: My post should explain everything in the correct way now, I think. Really read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2482969/4498838).